# C++ thread with lambda function

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ std thread with lambda function. In the following example, I don't know why the third argument (the lambda) for `for_each` has to use `std::thread &t` as its parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // vector container stores threads
    std::vector<std::thread> workers;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        workers.push_back(std::thread([]() 
        {
            std::cout << "thread function\n";
        }));
    }
    std::cout << "main thread\n";

    std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [](std::thread &t) 
    {
        t.join();
    });

    return 0;
}
```

With `std::thread t`, it gives the following compilation error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/algorithm:62:0,
                 from foo.cc:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::thread*, std::vector<std::thread> >; _Funct = main()::__lambda1]’:
foo.cc:20:3:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algo.h:4417:14: error: use of deleted function ‘std::thread::thread(std::thread&)’
  __f(*__first);
              ^
In file included from foo.cc:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/thread:125:5: error: declared here
     thread(thread&) = delete;
     ^
foo.cc:18:64: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘main()::__lambda1’
  std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [](std::thread t) {
```

I also checked that if I replace `std::thread` with `int` in my example, using `int t` as the third argument for `for_each` also works.

Comment: in order to affect the .join() you must be able to change the elements of the vector that is the subject of the business at hand.  since vectors are naturally passed as arguments by value you (opposite of how arrays are passed as arguments) must pass them by reference using the reference operator (&).  it is really that simple...don't over think it...

Comment: Also, a thread is not copy-constructible.

Answer (score 6):

```
std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [](std::thread &t) 
{
    t.join();
});
```

can be translated to

```
for (auto it = workers.begin(), end = workers.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
    std::thread &t = *it; // take a reference to the element, this is fine
    t.join();
}
```

When you leave out the `&` and take the thread by value then you get

```
for (auto it = workers.begin(), end = workers.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
    std::thread t = *it; // make a copy of the element, boom
    t.join();
}
```

You make a copy, but `std::thread` can't be copied, so you get an error.  For the manual loop you could "fix" that by using `std::move` like

```
for (auto it = workers.begin(), end = workers.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
    std::thread t = std::move(*it); // now we move into t
    t.join();
}
```

and you can get this same behavior in `std::for_each` by using [`std::make_move_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/make_move_iterator) like

```
std::for_each(std::make_move_iterator(workers.begin()),
              std::make_move_iterator(workers.end()), 
              [](std::thread t) 
{
    t.join();
});
```